# App interace layout direction returning left-to-right for right-to-left language

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization

I'm trying to develop a dual-lingual app, and for that adapt the UI to support both a left-to-right and a right-to-left language. I've switched my simulators settings to Hebrew, which is a RTL language, but it doesn't affect the view's layout at all (autolayout seems to be setup correctly), but more importantly this method (in my UITableViewController pictured below):

```
 if UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute(view.semanticContentAttribute) == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.RightToLeft {
            print("RTL")
        }
        else{
            print("LTR")
        }
```

prints `LTR`

Not sure if the method is wrong or if my app's settings weren't configured correctly. Here's a screenshot so you can see what my sample project looks like (see hebrew on top of status bar)

I follow internationalization support from [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html), but must have missed something (unless this is a bug).

Using Swift 2.0 & xcode 7.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `semanticContentAttribute` property is how the component should render itself when the layout direction changes.
Default is Unspecified.
So you always get false and

> "LTR"

Change your code to this and you'll get the correct print for the current layout:

```
if UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute(UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.Unspecified) == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.RightToLeft {
            print("RTL")
        }
        else{
            print("LTR")
        }
```